# Import Task / Identity column throwing error

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

Software:  SSMS 2008 R2, Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate (for creating objects)

This is very strange and I would love for someone to be able to explain it to me. I have two versions of the same table. The production version has two fields, and the Test version has the same two fields PLUS a RecordID field (identity field).

Here's the table definition in Test:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table]
(
    [Field1] varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [Field2] varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [RecordId] smallint identity not null,
    constraint [CIDX_Table] unique clustered ([RecordId]) with (data_compression=page),
)
```

Here's where the error gets thrown... I try to refresh the Test version with the production data (Field1 & field2). Since the production version doesn't have the identity column, I don't map it. The identity column should auto-increment. My research shows that if you don't explicitly state seed and increment, the default is (1,1). The import task wizard fails (even with Enable Identity Insert checked!). The error:

"Cannot insert NULL value into field RecordID."

Here is the REALLY strange part. Initially, I thought the error was that the seed and increment were missing, so I modified the table definition as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table]
(
    [Field1] varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [Field2] varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [RecordId] smallint identity(1,1) not null,
    constraint [CIDX_Table] unique clustered ([RecordId]) with (data_compression=page),
)
```

Then I tried to refresh the table again, and the EXACT SAME SSIS package succeeded and copied both columns and auto-incremented the RecordID field.

My question: What the heck!? Why does explicitly stating seed/increment allow the import wizard to insert values and auto-increment if the default when you do not explicitly state them is still 1,1?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `NOT NULL` in `smallint` identity of `RecordId` column. Because the identity is already not null:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table]
(
    [Field1] varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [Field2] varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [RecordId] smallint identity(1,1),
    constraint [CIDX_Table] unique clustered ([RecordId]) with (data_compression=page),
)
```